# How do I call submit in mvc app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have mvc3 web app.
inside that I have one Enquiry form once I submit that form it should save all data into database for that I have used Entity Framework.

EnquiryController.cs

```
 public class EnquiryController : Controller
    {
        aspnetdbEntities dbEntities = new aspnetdbEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Enquiry/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        //
        // GET: /Enquiry/
        public ActionResult Enquiry()
        {
            return View();
        }
        //
        //POST: /Enquiry/
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Enquiry(Enquiry enquiry)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                dbEntities.Enquiries.AddObject(enquiry);
                dbEntities.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(enquiry);
        }
    }
```

Enquiry.cshtml

```
@model MyWeb.Models.Enquiry

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Enquiry";
}

<h2>Enquiry</h2>
<div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Enquiry Form</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

But when I clicked on `Submit` button it is not working no round rip no refresh 
please help me where i go wrong i'm newbie.

Comment: you can `submit` something using a `<form>` or a javascript call, generally we use the `<form>` tag. Either append that manually or your the `Html` helper in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ashuthinks,

just add the htmlHelper (for forms) to your view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
  // exisiting fieldset stuff
  <fieldset>... bla</fieldset>
}
```

around your fieldset and you're good to go